# How to use Material UI TreeView with Recursive TreeItem Component with added state

Tags: reactjs, recursion, material-ui, react-functional-component

I'm using Material UI's `TreeView` and `TreeItem` Component. I want to add extra state that will be unique to each treeItem to manage drag and drop with react-dnd.

The default way Material UI says to do this is like this:

```
const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <TreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name} ref={drag}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children) ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node)) : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );

  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpanded={['root']}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      {renderTree(data)}
    </TreeView>
  );
```

But because I need to have individual unique state for each tree item this won't work **(For some reason only the last TreeItem rendered has the drag functionality and I'm assuming it will work if each one had it's own variable).** To get around this I created a component called TreeItemWrapper that looks like this

```
export default function TreeItemWrapper(props) {
    const [{isDragging}, drag] = useDrag({
        item:  {
            type: ItemTypes.ROW,
        },
        collect: monitor => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
        })
    });


    return (
        <TreeItem
            key={props.id}
            nodeId={props.id}
            label={props.label}
            ref={drag}
            opacity={isDragging ? '0.5' : '1'}
        >
        </TreeItem>
    )
}
```

My renderTree method now looks like this

```
return (
            <TreeItemWrapper id={nodes.id} label={nodes.label}>
                {Array.isArray(nodes.children) ? nodes.children.map( (node) => renderTree(node)) : null}
            </TreeItemWrapper>
        );
```

Which isn't working. It's only rendering the top node of the tree. I wonder if I'm missing something simple about how react works? I put some log statements in `TreeItemWrapper` and they only get called once for the top node of the tree

Comment: Did you get solution for the same I am looking for the same

Comment: @priyankaUkirde, Yes, but I just downloaded the source for the TreeItem component and put customizations in there

Answer (score 0):

Check content in these urls:

https://material-ui.com/zh/components/tree-view/#tree-view

https://codesandbox.io/s/zm6mh

You need build a data structure for it recursively:

```
const data: RenderTree = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Parent',
  extra: 'xxxx', <--- add extra data like this
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
      extra: 'xxxx', <--- add extra data like this
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Another choice is using this library:
https://github.com/helfi92/material-ui-treeview#readme